# Unable to import Django within my virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble importing Django within my virtual environment, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/thecorp/django/olympus/virt_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.version'
```

This happens when I "python manage.py runserver" or when I just import Django in general. I've tried checking my installation and I can't find anything immediately wrong - Django shows up when I "pip freeze" and is included within my PATH. Any help or advice would be appreciated. This is all in Python 3.6 by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `pip freeze` in the *activated* virtual environment? What version of Django do you use?

Comment: Nevermind... this has been solved, I uninstalled Django and installed it again and somehow that fixed it. Go figure. I was running pip freeze in the environment and I'm using version 1.10.2